# Postfix + LDAP + Recipient Delimiter

Tags: postfix, ldap

I'm trying to get my Postfix and LDAP-backend to accept recipent delimiters (aka address extensions).

The rest of the mail system is working fine, but when an email is received with an extension (e.g. coops+test@domain.com), it tries to look up "coops+test" against the LDAP service and fails. Obviously this is wrong, and it should strip out the "+test" part.

In my postfix config the string being passed to the LDAP service is "%s", per an example line below:

```
accounts_query_filter = (&(objectClass=MailAccount)(mail=%s)(accountActive=TRUE)(delete=FALSE))
```

Is there a postfix variable which represents the email account minus the extension? I've found a similar post [here](http://groups.google.com/group/mailing.postfix.users/browse_thread/thread/fc7af523222e79c6?utoken=zZ9P4DgAAABAqTxmL7n7CN6lEPM1AykNg7-4SwjwlVVuJwn2fniRDk8nS-Z07AeilJlKl-0s4iIIZtUD2SIQpqJjYV6PC8D4), but no actual solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the man-page ldap_table(5) the possibilities are:

```
%%     This is replaced by a literal ’%’ character. (Postfix 2.2 and later).

%s     This is replaced by the input key.  RFC 2254 quoting is used to make sure  that  the  input  key
       does not add unexpected metacharacters.

%u     When  the  input  key  is  an  address of the form user@domain, %u is replaced by the (RFC 2254)
       quoted local part of the address.  Otherwise, %u is replaced by the entire  search  string.   If
       the localpart is empty, the search is suppressed and returns no results.

%d     When  the  input  key  is  an  address of the form user@domain, %d is replaced by the (RFC 2254)
       quoted domain part of the address.  Otherwise, the search is suppressed and returns no  results.

%[SUD] The  upper-case equivalents of the above expansions behave in the query_filter parameter identi‐
       cally to their lower-case counter-parts. With the  result_format  parameter  (previously  called
       result_filter  see the COMPATIBILITY section and below), they expand to the corresponding compo‐
       nents of input key rather than the result value.

       The above %S, %U and %D expansions are available with Postfix 2.2 and later.

%[1-9] The patterns %1, %2, ... %9 are replaced by the corresponding most significant component of  the
       input key’s domain. If the input key is user@mail.example.com, then %1 is com, %2 is example and
       %3 is mail. If the input key is unqualified or does not have enough domain components to satisfy
       all the specified patterns, the search is suppressed and returns no results.

       The above %1, ..., %9 expansions are available with Postfix 2.2 and later.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this:

```
recipient_delimiter = +
```

In you main.cf